WebClient custom response headers added with ExchangeFilterFunction not getting propagated back to client
I am using ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor method to transform the Response received by the WebClient.

Add new Headers to response
Modify the response Body

ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> Mono.just( clientResponse .mutate() .body("This got modified") .header("example-header", "EXAMPLE-HEADER") .build()) );
I am triggering the WebClient through a Postman Call and That will call.
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder() .filter(WebClientFilters.modifyResponseHeaders()) .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)) .build();
return webClient.get() .uri("http://localhost:8080/hello-annotated") .retrieve() .bodyToMono(String.class);
But When I see the Response Headers received back at Postman I can't see the newly added Headers via the Filter Function.
Postman Headers
But I can clearly see the Response Body has Transformed as expected.
What is causing the issue for custom headers not getting propagated back to client?
I tried with mutate method as well as from methd of ClientResponse class. But got the same issue.
